# SpringJUnitRunner based tests fail under PIT

Tags: spring-test, spring-junit, pitest

I have a project that utilizes SpringJUnitRunner for testing the controllers and filters. When I run the test normally, everything runs fine. However, when I run the tests with PIT I get the following exception for every test using the SpringJUnitRunner:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : .springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:155)
at org.springfr
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : amework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
at org.springframework.test.context.j
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : unit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : (ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
a
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : t org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.ru
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : nners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeT
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : estClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE :  org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
at org.pitest.junit.adapter.CustomRunnerExecutor.run(CustomRunnerExecutor.java:42)
at org.pitest.junit.adapter.AdaptedJUnitTestUnit.execute(AdaptedJUni
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : tTestUnit.java:85)
at org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageDecorator.execute(CoverageDecorator.java:50)
at org.pitest.execute.containers.UnContainer.submit(UnContainer.java:45)
at org.pitest.execute.Pitest$3.run(Pitest.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(
11:53:55 PM PIT >> FINE : SLAVE : Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
```

It should be noted that we have also had issues using Emma for code coverage on these same tests, and have had to switch to Jacoco as a result.

Is there any known incompatibilities between SpringJUnitRunner and PIT, or is there some kind of configuration change I can make that will allow these two to play nicely together?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is no known general issue with using the SpringJUnitRunner with PIT - I've mutation tested several spring projects without issue.

From the stacktrace it looks like this might be some sort of classpath issue causing spring to read in duplicate configuration.

Does anything look incorrect/strange/duplicated in the classpath that pitest prints out to the console?

Comment: OK, after exhaustive looking through the logs, it seems that PIT is adding files from both target/classes and target/test-classes to the classpath. This in turn is causing our applicationContext*.xml files to be parsed twice (they are referenced as "classpath:**/META-INF/applicationContext*.xml"). This seems to be part of the problem. Question is, how to have only one of those folders thrown on the classpath during PIT. (Note that this does NOT seem to be an issue during the "normal" test run.)

Comment: @Jesse Any follow up on how you solved this issue? For my case since I'm running on a windows machine, I'm setting the useClasspathFile flag for pitest, is this something you were doing as well? Could it be causing the problem?